# Reference unknown number of variables / func_get_args()

Tags: php

How do I make a reference to an unknown number of variables?

An example:

```
referenceme($a, $b, $c);
referenceme($a, $b);
referenceme($a, $b, $c, $d);

// What I theoretically want to do:
function referenceme(&func_get_args()){
  ...
}
```

If this is not possible, I'd like to know how the bind_result() function of prepared statements is doing exactly this?
http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

What I don't want to do:

```
function referenceme(&$a = false, &$b = false, &$c = false, &$d = false, &$e = false, ...){
  ...
}
```

I don't want to pass an array either.

What I'm actually trying to do, is to write myself a class to handle my database queries via prepared statements. So I'd like to imitate some functions. But bind_result() is a complete mystery to me.

Might there be some crazy solution? Like counting the number of variables before the actual function is called and redirect it to call to an eval, which is "creating" the needed function?

Comment: Please consult the Bible (http://ro1.php.net/func_get_args)

Comment: There is no good way of doing this in PHP. The only way to do that is using debug_backtrace but it's pretty ugly. Why don't you try an OOP approach? Something like $preparedStmt->add($a)? You can also do it chainable $preparedStmt->add($a)->add($b)->add($c);

Comment: Thank you, Alex Barroso, I like your add() idea. It's not what I was looking for initially, but this seems to be a good workaround to me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one area `mysqli` falls down on the job. (PDO actually has a [much cleaner implementation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) for bound parameters). If you're using `mysqlnd` (check for a `mysqlnd` block in `phpinfo()`) I would HIGHLY suggest you skip `bind_result()` and use the much more modern [get_result()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) instead. What's different is that `get_result` returns a [mysqli_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object, which means your results are more encapsulated and flexible.

Now, to your other question about variable arguments. You're right in that [func_get_args](http://www.php.net/func_get_args) can return the arguments passed but this quickly becomes an untenable proposition for you, especially if you're looking to use something like [bind_param()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), which not only passes by reference but also requires you to specify the data type as well. Add in that this is an infrastructure layer to your application and you could very well wind up with a function call that lists dozens of fields.

If you're building a class, you should inject your DB pointer (best to use the OOP here and not procedural) and then have your class do the work around it with getter and setter functions that would set internal data and then pass it along to your `mysqli` class. This example is oversimplified (it does no serious error checking) but it should give you a boost to hopefully do what you need doing.

```
class dbHelper {
    /** @var \mysqli */
    protected $mysqli;
    /** @var array */
    protected $args = array('');

    public function __construct(\mysqli $mysqli) {
        $this->mysqli = $mysqli;
    }

    public function setArgs($data, $type) {
       $this->args[0] .= $type;
       $this->args[] = &$data;
       return $this; // Chain your calls if you want
    }

    public function reset() {
         $this->args = array('');
         return $this;
    }

    public function doQuery($sql) {
         $prep = $this->mysqli->prepare($sql);
         if(count($this->args) > 1) call_user_func_array(array($prep, 'bind_param'), $this->args);
         $prep-execute();
         return $prep->get_result();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much appreciated. I'll have a look into mysqlnd - it looks promising. Your dbhelper class is indeed a good example of what I'd like to create.

Comment: I'd really like to give you more credit for this answer, because this is an model answer on which I can improve my programming skills.